# How to change color of Bootstrap warning class table row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Bootstrap and CSS and having some issues with coloring of tables. I have a table like this with some rows which have the class warning:

```
<table class="table table-bordered grocery-crud-table table-hover">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="warning">
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How do I change the color of rows with the warning class? I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
   .warning {
      background-color:#76A0D3;
    }
```

Comment: Do you load your custom css _after_ bootstrap's?

Comment: At face value - that rule is valid and should work. Unless - it's being over-qualified by another rule with more specificity.

Comment: LGSo, yes my css is loaded after bootstrap's. I'll try to change the order and see if it works.

Comment: maybe try .table .warning {  }

Comment: Changing the order of the custom css doesn't work. .table .warning { } doesn't work either.

Comment: Your HTML seems invalid. Also check official bootstrap tables documentation (there is a section for the colored cells/rows): http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case the `td`'s color covers the `tr`

```css
table tr td {
  padding: 20px;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.warning {
  background: #76A0D3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-bordered grocery-crud-table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="warning">
      <td>
        Hey
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you set it on the `td` it works as expected

```css
table tr td {
  padding: 20px;
}
.warning {
  background: #76A0D3 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-bordered grocery-crud-table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="warning">
        Hey
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

**UPDATED**

```
table.table.table-hover tr.warning,
table.table.table-bordered tr.warning,
table.table.grocery-crud-table tr.warning{
    background-color:#76A0D3;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hLbu0hov/

Answer (score 0):

add !important to background-color:

```
.warning{
  background-color:#76A0D3 !important;
}
```